# How to edit a UV Map Color?

Tags: texturing, uv, unity, color

i imported a fbx from a unity UV Mapped textured asset and am trying to reassign a color or two in blender, is this possible?

[image: UV map setup]

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand the goal of your question. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @Tsybe So i have a .fbx from unity which has 1 material that is uv mapped to 5 colors. I am trying to change one of the colors in blender using the UV mapping editor and then import the changed fbx to unity. For more detail, the object is a road, the road has grass as one of the colors/materials and I want to change the grass color.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you will need a material that is assigned to the object (road) after this you need to create the texture for the road and connect it to the material. *Example:*

[image]

**The texture:** You have to create a simple image, even in Blender. Then you need to separate that image into 5 parts for the 5 colors. Then in the UV editor, you have to move the UV islands to the required color. *Example:*
[image]

*Blend file if you need:*

[image]

*Texture for the blend file:* https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BMWL.png